# Error in fn (par...): unused arguments

Tags: r

I am getting the following error message when I create the 'bootstrapped' object:

`Error in fn(par, ...) : 
  unused arguments (x = c(18.1818181818182, 8.08080808080808, 62.6262626262626, 26.2626262626263, 76.7676767676768, 18.1818181818182, 38.3838383838384, 69.6969696969697, 64.6464646464647, 5.05050505050505`

When I use the debugging tool, it says the following:

`Function: [Anonymous function] (optim())`

But I've been looking at my function for a bit and cannot spot any problems:

```
x<-xy$x
y<-xy$y
fn_bootstrap=function(x,y){
bootstrapping<-sample(1:100, replace = T)
fit2<-optim(c(1,1),
fn=myfun,
method="L-BFGS-B",
lower=c(0,-1),
upper=c(15,15),
x=x[bootstrapping], 
y=y[bootstrapping])

return(c(fit1$par,fit1$convergence) )
}

replications<-10000
bootstrapped<-replicate(replications, bootstrap(x=x,y=y))
```

**Edit**: Sample of x,y

`x        y
 1 4.683172
 2 5.152812
 3 4.133874
 4 3.294114
 5 3.871276
 6 3.792533
 7 3.551182

 8 3.389954
 9 2.202404
10 3.730870 
11 3.223740
12 2.109984
13 3.129297
14 2.830958
15 2.303632
16 1.766578
17 1.749364
18 1.735230
19 1.654743
20 2.033441`

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(xy)` or if it is too big of `dput(head(xy, 20))`?

Comment: The `)` after `y[bootstrapping]` belongs after `upper=c(15,15)`. The `optim` function does not have paramaters named `x` or `y`. You should consider using a coding environment that has syntax highlighting and parenthesis help, etc., and try to use good coding style practices. This will help you track down errors much more quickly.

Comment: In you call it's `fn_bootstrap` (you are missing the `fn`). And when I correct that, it throws `Error in (function (par)  : object 'myfun' not found`.

Comment: Thanks - using RMarkdown. Is there a better program?